# updating selects with jquery

Tags: jquery

I made a quick fiddle (doesnt work) that kinda illustrates what I have. I have a set of selects and the possibility to add more. Now, these get populated dynamically based on an array of objects. What I want to do is that my selects dont use the same options if one is used. For instance `select-1` has options 1-2-3-5 as `select-2`, but when the user selects one option that option needs to disappear on the other selects as well as the ones that got dynamically created. These should also be reversible. thanks for all your help.[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5YhpW/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified this code somewhat using selectors.

Here you only need to have one event, and you can use a comma in your selector (or another multiple-match selector) that hits everything you want:

```
    $('#xAxis,#yAxis').on('change',function(){
        setControls();
        $('#main-controls select')
          .each(function()
          {
               $('#main-controls select')
                 .not($(this))
                 .find('option[value=' + $(this).val() +']')
                 .remove();
          });
    });
```

The strategy is to set up the controls, then find any other controls that have what we just selected. This would be a lot easier if we could `hide()` options, but unfortunately that doesn't work cross-browser; we have to `remove()` them.

In `setControls` the modification is to only add the options to selects that don't already have the option. Then we can call it whenever we want to restore the selects to their original choices (without losing current selections).

```
    function setControls(){
        $.each(series,function(k,v){
            $('#xAxis,#yAxis')
              .filter(':not(:has(option[value=' + k +']))')
              .append($('<option>')
              .attr({value: k})
              .text(v.name));
        });   
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5YhpW/8/

Comment: As you can see I've not worked with JQuery that much. One thing I notice on your code is that, if you pick int on the 1st select you don't see int available on the second but as soon as you make a selection int reappears. Thanks for your help -Louie

Comment: @LouieV Oops! I've updated the code so that doesn't happen (http://jsfiddle.net/5YhpW/8/) Instead of just removing items from the changing dropdown, we need to remove items from all of them (since they were just restored).

Comment: Great it works like a charm. Now I tried to implement it to dynamically added selects but can't get it to work. Could you give me a hand? [link]http://jsfiddle.net/5YhpW/16/

Comment: Well the issue is that when the new select gets created all of the options are available to choose from instead of the unused ones. I figure that I can set a flag where the option gets used but not when it becomes available. Altough it gets fiex if ou pick the unused option.

Comment: SOLVED IT! Just had to make an extra call to update select after creating it. http://jsfiddle.net/5YhpW/17/